# C++ How to capitalize first word of each sentence/line in a string?

Tags: c++, string, line, capitalization

I am loosing my hair right now. I have a string, which i manipulate to start a new line/sentence after a punctuation, but I cant understand how I can capitalize the first word of each sentence? Except for this, i can not get out of the loop to change the dot into a dot and new line.

```
int main()
{
    string const txt1 = "Candy is good for your health.";
    string const text2 = "All kids should buy candy.";
    string const text3 = "Candy nowadays is a hit among kids.";
    string const text4 = "Every meal should include candy.";


    string text = text1 + text2 + text3 + text4;

    transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), ::tolower);

    while (text.find("candy") != string::npos)
        text.replace(text.find("candy"), 3, "fruit");
    string_replace_all(text, ".", ".\n");
```

This is what i have added so far:

```
string line, total = ""; istringstream stream(text);
while (getline(stream, line, '\n'))
{
    if (line.size() > 0)
        total += (char)toupper(line[0]) + line.substr(1) + "\n";
    else total += "\n";
}
```

Comment: @Thesar did my post work for you?

Comment: It got deleted before i tried @JakeFreeman. I will try it now.

Comment: Also make sure you put `\n` characters between your strings.

Comment: What library does getline belong to? Cant get it to work. 

Errors: 

E0349 no operator "+" matches these operands 
E0304 no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list
E0070 incomplete type is not allowed (stream)

@JakeFreeman

Comment: @Thesar make sure you `include <string>`

Comment: @JakeFreeman i have it, and also using std::getline;

Won't recognize it.

Comment: @Thesar make sure you `include <sstream>` for the `istringstream`

Comment: Ohh, now they work after I included sstream. But it wont accept '+' as a operator in |  toupper(line[0]) + line.substr(1) + "\n"; |  @JakeFreeman

Comment: @Thesar I edited my post to fix that by adding `to_string(toupper(line[0])`.

Comment: @JakeFreeman Now i can compile it, but nothing happens. No capitalization is done :/.

Comment: Please confirm that you have text1+"\n"+text2... @Thesar

Comment: I have this: string_replace_all(text, ".", ".\n"); | to insert \n after each dot. @JakeFreeman, but i will try this manually

Comment: @JakeFreeman did add "\n" between each string, didnt help :/

Comment: @Thesar I am testing on my computer now

Comment: @Thesar I just tested a slight modification and it works. instead of to_string() just cast to char

Comment: @JakeFreeman thank you for your time. Really appreciate it. Didn't work with (char) neither. Please check my question, i have added your pile of the code, and see if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Thesar all the sentences start with a capital letter

Comment: @JakeFreeman then I am doing something else wrong, don't know what tho. I want to thank you for your help.

Comment: @Thesar thanks I'll still be happy help if you figure what is wrong

Comment: @JakeFreeman can it be because i convert all chars to lowecase, and it loops this transform all the time?

Comment: @Thesar the only difference between my tests and your code is string_replace_all is that a custom function.

Comment: @JakeFreeman yes, it's the only function that is allowing me to replace "." with ".\n" without getting stuck in a while loop that searches for "." to replace it, and allways finds one.

| while (text.find(".") != string::npos) |
| text.insert(t1.find("."), ".\n"); | makes my program go all black because i get stuck in the loop due to the fact that find always finds a "."

Comment: @Thesar what include has the function?

Comment: @JakeFreeman if you mean the string_replace_all: it is a std, with a void declaration

Comment: @Thesar I could not find that function, everything except that is the same so make sure its correct.

Comment: @JakeFreeman

 while ((pos = alltxt.find(".", pos)) != std::string::npos)
 {
  alltxt.replace(pos, 1, ".\n");
  pos += 2; 
} |||| What to add after pos+=2; to capitalize the character after that position? I think this might solve my issue

Comment: Ok let me know @Thesar

Comment: @JakeFreeman
Am Idoing it right, to find the first character after pos=+2?

 ||| alltxt.find_first_of(' ');
  toupper(' ');
  alltxt.replace(pos, 1, ".\n");
  pos += 2; // move past the dot (and the extra '\n'
  alltxt.find_first_of(' ');
  toupper(' '); |||

Comment: @Thesar try it manually and with the function I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simply way to this would be:

```
string line, total = ""; istringstream stream(someString);
while(getline(stream, line, '\n')) 
{
    if(line.size() > 0) 
        total += (char)toupper(line[0]) + line.substr(1) + "\n";
    else total+= "\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.